# How to convert the [AnyObject] Array to string in swift

Tags: ios, swift

For example: Array like ["A12", 1, 2, "Test"].
My expected result should be able to bind in the textfield or else to get as string with component seperator (,)

Comment: would you like to get Strings only from the array?

Comment: Try using `joinWithSeparator(",")` it should return a string like "A12,1,2,Test"

Comment: It's not clear what the expected output is: an array of strings, or a string. Can you clarify this in the question? Maybe give an example of how your output should look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First map the values to `String` values, and then just join them using separator that you like:

```
let description: String = ["A12", 1, 2, "Test"].map{ String(describing: $0) }.joined(separator: ", ")
print(description)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done with this,

```
    let array: [Any] = ["A12", 1, 2, "Test"]
    let tmpArray = array.map({ return String(describing: $0)})
    let string = tmpArray.joined(separator: ",")
    print(string)
```